# How do you merge multiple OpenID providers?

Tags: openid

Right now, I use myopenid.com, which works just fine, but with Google, Facebook, etc. now providing OpenID, I'd like to merge all my IDs into one.  Is this possible or am I missing the point of OpenID completely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, in theory, you'd be able to use any openID to login to any openID enabled site, so you'd never need to have more than one... Unfortunately, the major players (facebook, google, yahoo) are only *Providing* OpenID, Which means you can use theirs, but it's not full OpenID support.

The real point of OpenID is to have a single login that works everywhere, unfortunately, we're not quite there yet...

Comment: I gotcha.  So I can use Google OpenID wherever OpenID is accepted but can't use my non-google OpenID to log-in to Google, FB, etc. Bummer.

Comment: It makes sense to merge. myopenid.com is very unreliable (and closing/closed down). You will lose access to your login if it happens.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you'll want to pick one that you feel represents your identity.  Unless you want your identity to be owned by a company, the best option is to [setup OpenID delegation](http://www.anotherblogger.com/2009/05/30/openid-delegation-makes-vidoops-failure-painless/) so that you can potentially switch providers but use a domain name you control to represent yourself on the web.

For example, I'm currently using Verisign's PIP as my provider, but I use my personal domain aaronhockley.com as the URL that represents my identity to OpenID relying parties.

Comment: That I've done.  I have my own domain and have setup OpenID delegation, so I can switch providers.  The big issue is merging them all.  I'd like my domain OpenID, Google OpenID and Facebook OpenID to all hit the same place.  Again, unless I'm completely missing the point.